# Connecting to postgres with classic ADO

Tags: postgresql, ms-access, asp-classic

I'm in the process of migrating from Access to Postgres. I already have the Postgres db up and running and the data migrated. There are two websites I have to migrate, one that uses asp.net, which I switched fine to the new db using Npgsql but I'm running into trouble for the older one, which uses classic ASP.

Currently the website connects to the access db using something similar do this for every query:

```
Set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.ActiveConnection=MM_intranet_STRING
rs.Open <query string here>
```

The current connection string is:

```
"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=<path to file>"
```

It seems to me that to keep everything working with as little changes as possible (in other words: not touching the RecordSets) I'd have to install a Postgres ADO oledb provider on the server, this way I'd only need to replace the connection string.

Unfortunately, the only free such driver I found was [PgOleDb, a beta release from 2006](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/oledb/).

Am I missing something? Is there another way of doing this or another actively developed driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Access connection string you cited in your question is an ODBC connection string, not an OLEDB connection string. Try using the PostgreSQL ODBC driver (psqlODBC):

http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/

Comment: For some reason I became convinced it was using OLEDB, thank you!